# How to add the line breaker using CF and LF for message events? This changes have to make in CFG that generates the password reset data

Tags: passwords, line-breaks, syslog, idm

I want to have the events break as each single event? How can this be done? Is there any way to do it using CR and LF?

I don't know much about CR and LF, Got eyes into this. Not sure if this will help or not.